# Find overlapping columns ratio in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Dataframe (Assume all values as categorical):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"a" : [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5],
"b" : [2,1,3,4,5],
"c" : [1,3,4,2,5]},
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I want to find what percentage of overlap is present between different columns

```
check_a_b = df.a == df.b
check_b_c = df.b == df.c
check_a_c = df.a == df.c

print(np.sum(check_a_b)/len(check_a_b)) # 0.6
print(np.sum(check_b_c)/len(check_b_c)) # 0.2
print(np.sum(check_a_c)/len(check_a_c)) # 0.4
```

Final output required as a matrix / DataFrame ( Triangular matrix):

```
    a    b    c
a       0.6   0.4 
b             0.2
c
```

Now I want to implement this for 15 columns in an automated way for a data of more than 100K rows. 
What would be the optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping down to `numpy` is usually efficient. Only return to `pandas` when you have the result.

```
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "b" : [2,1,3,4,5],
                   "c" : [1,3,4,2,5]},
                  index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

a = df.values

d = {(i, j): np.mean(a[:, i] == a[:, j]) for i, j in combinations(range(a.shape[1]), 2)}

res, c, vals = np.zeros((a.shape[1], a.shape[1])), \
               list(map(list, zip(*d.keys()))), list(d.values())

res[c[0], c[1]] = vals

res_df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

#      a    b    c
# a  0.0  0.6  0.4
# b  0.0  0.0  0.2
# c  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "b" : [2,1,3,4,5],
                   "c" : [1,3,4,2,5]},
                  index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

df_out = pd.DataFrame()
for i in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    s = pd.DataFrame((df[i[0]] == df[i[1]]).mean(),index=[i[0]], columns=[i[1]])
    df_out = pd.concat([df_out,s])

df_out.sum(level=0).reindex(df.columns).reindex(df.columns, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
a  0.0  0.6  0.4
b  0.0  0.0  0.2
c  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: In my experience, `pd.concat` inside a loop can be v expensive. I think you can add your results to a list and concat the list of dataframes at the end.

Comment: @jpp great idea!  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is on way

```
Yourdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,index=df.columns)    
Yourdf=Yourdf.stack(dropna=False).to_frame().apply(lambda x : (df[x.name[0]]==df[x.name[1]]).sum()/len(df),axis=1).unstack()   
Yourdf=Yourdf.where(np.triu(np.ones(Yourdf.shape),1).astype(np.bool))
Yourdf
Out[169]: 
    a    b    c
a NaN  0.6  0.4
b NaN  NaN  0.2
c NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Update : mention by Scott

*Change to `mean`*

```
Yourdf=Yourdf.stack(dropna=False).to_frame().apply(lambda x : (df[x.name[0]]==df[x.name[1]]).mean(),axis=1).unstack()
```

Comment: Can you use 'mean' instead of sum and divide by length? +1 I like using triu.

Comment: @ScottBoston Yep , will change to mean